# Sending SMS via PHP using Curl

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, curl

I have this form below that is suppose to send a POST request to the backend, which will in turn send an SMS, on submit:

```
<form id="sms" method="post">
      <input type="number" name="mobile" id="mobile" class="text"/>
      <button type="button" name="sub" value="Submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

I got this from the backend guy with no other details. I found some online tutorials but I couldn't make anything of it.

```
curl -X POST \
  https://example.com/gateway/sms \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 's: APP' \
  -d '{ 
   "mobile": "1112223333"
 }'
```

Could anyone point me to a PHP processor that could process this info? My knowledge is very limited.

Comment: PHP can't send SMS on it's own. You need to use some service for that and asking for suggestions for off-site services are off-topic here on SO. You need to do the research yourself.

Comment: Alright. Thanks.

Comment: Are you actually posting to `https://example.com`, or is that a placeholder for the real service you are using?

Comment: That is a placeholder for the actual working URL.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you can just talk to the backend person, but from what I can tell, they are asking you to create a POST request, using javascript, that does the same thing as the curl command in your example.

Your form is not going to work as is, because it will send the request to the backend using an encoded form, but the backend expects JSON.

You need to capture the form submission, and then do something like

```
url = 'https://example.com/gateway/sms';
data = {mobile: _get_number_from_form() };
success = function(data) { console.log(data); };
headers = {s: 'APP'};
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: success,
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: headers
});
```

[postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) and the network tab in Chrome will be useful here.

Comment: That's correct. I'm relatively new to this. So I have to send the data in JSON format to the backend? My initial thought was to create a PHP form processor and send the mobile number and their backend takes care of the rest. Either way, I won't know how to proceed. I couldn't make a head/tail of your code too though. Thank You so much. I'm looking at solutions online.

Comment: Yea, if the curl command is all we have to go on. The jQuery example I gave above will convert the javscript dict to JSON properly.

Comment: I've edited my comment above. Let me search further and see if there's a ready to use solution. This is beyond me actually. Thanks so much.

Comment: In your mental model, what is the relationship between the "PHP form processor" and the rest of the backend? I had assumed that your PHP form processor _is_ in the backend.

Comment: I have no idea actually. I have dealt with PHP form processors and so thought that would be it; capture `mobile` and send it to the URL `https://example.com/gateway/sms`. I was clearly wrong. btw, how would the HTML look like for the code you've posted?

Comment: I'm assuming, your code would be under `$.ajax({` and end with `});` as per other threads found online. But I don't know how the HTML or the form would be like.

Comment: Maybe this tutorial can clear things up: http://www.developerdrive.com/2013/04/turning-a-form-element-into-json-and-submiting-it-via-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

```
 $inNumber = $_REQUEST["inNumber"];
 $sender = $_REQUEST["sender"];
 $keyword = $_REQUEST["keyword"];
 $content = $_REQUEST["content"];
 $email = $_REQUEST["email"];
 $credits = $_REQUEST["credits"];

// Account details
        $apiKey = urlencode('jpvpyVsTv50-O7te5yiz3oP1DjMkdsiuHSUBS');

        // Message details
        $numbers = $_REQUEST["sender"];
        $sender = urlencode('JHSSVE');

        $text = "Thank you for your order";
        $message = rawurlencode($text);
     $test = true;

        // Prepare data for POST request
        $data = array('apikey' => $apiKey, 'numbers' => $numbers, "sender" => $sender, "message" => $message);

        // Send the POST request with cURL
        $ch = curl_init('https://api.textlocal.in/send/');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```